# Using Simulink.Breakpoint for lookup tables in Simulink

Tags: simulink, lookup-tables

I am trying to use Simulink.Breakpoint in lookup tables in Simulink. Here is how I define the lookup table.

```
test_lut = Simulink.LookupTable;
test_lut.Table.DataType = 'single';
test_lut.Table.Value = single([1 2 3 4 5]);

test_lut.CoderInfo.StorageClass = 'ExportedGlobal';
test_lut.StructTypeInfo.DataScope = 'Exported';

test_lut_bp = Simulink.Breakpoint;
test_lut_bp.CoderInfo.StorageClass = 'ExportedGlobal';
test_lut_bp.Breakpoints.Value = single([1 2 3 4 5]);

test_lut.BreakpointsSpecification = 'Reference';
test_lut.Breakpoints = {'test_lut_bp'};
```

However, the following error appears when I run the model. 
[This error appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZPIN.png), is there anything I am doing wrong here? how should we use simulink.breakpoints properly?

Comment: Please try pasting text instead of screenshots. :)

Comment: It's from a dialog-box I can't copy the text !